# How do I create a BigQuery view with standard SQL using the Java API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can create views using the Java API, but the query needs to be legacy sql:

```
public void createView(String dataSet, String viewName, String query) throws Exception {

    Table content = new Table();
    TableReference tableReference = new TableReference();
    tableReference.setTableId(viewName);
    tableReference.setDatasetId(dataSet);
    tableReference.setProjectId(projectId);
    content.setTableReference(tableReference);

    ViewDefinition view = new ViewDefinition();

    view.setQuery(query);
    content.setView(view);
    LOG.debug("View to create: " + content);
    try {
        if (tableExists(dataSet, viewName)) {
            bigquery.tables().delete(projectId, dataSet, viewName).execute();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Could not delete table", e);
    }

    bigquery.tables().insert(projectId, dataSet, content).setProjectId(projectId).execute();
}
```

Is there a way to create a BQ view with standard sql using the API?

Comment: I'm not seeing a related option in the API docs. What if you use `#standardSQL` at the start of the query itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `setUseLegacySQL(false)` on the `ViewDefinition` object.

```
[..]
ViewDefinition view = new ViewDefinition();
view.setQuery(query);
view.setUseLegacySql(false); //<-- you're missing this
content.setView(view);
[..]
```

See the API docs [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/ViewDefinition.html#setUseLegacySql(java.lang.Boolean)).

Comment: you are right. I was using an older version of the api

Comment: here's a link to the "new" version (ignore the big red "this is the old version" warning): https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/bigquery/v2

/boggle

Comment: @AndreyFedorov - not following you. That's the older API. The new (more idiomatic) one is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery

Comment: oooh so new so idiomatic. could you point me to the setUseLegacySql method you are talking about? it seems my command-f is broken https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/ViewDefinition.java

Comment: indeed, the new API unfortunately no longer offers this method : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813165/specify-sql-dialect-for-viewdefinition-in-bigquery-api

Answer (score 0):

With the new API, you can use the "#standardSQL" notation to avoid the default LegacySQL setting (the setUseLegacySql() method no longer exists in the new API).

Here is an example:

```
ViewDefinition tableDefinition = ViewDefinition.newBuilder("#standardSQL\n  WITH A AS (select 1 as foo) SELECT * from A").build();
```