# Specify SQL dialect for ViewDefinition in BigQuery API

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

There are two APIs for manipulating BigQuery entities (Datasets, Tables, Views, etc.)...

1. The old (deprecated) API: com.google.api.services.bigquery
2. The new API: com.google.cloud.bigquery

In the old API, the View class has a boolean flag that specifies whether the associated query is using legacy or standard SQL.  That flag is accessed via the methods:

- getUseLegacySql
- setUseLegacySql

The new API introduces the ViewDefinition class, but it does not have the boolean flag.

How do you specify the SQL dialect for a ViewDefinition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is indeed broken.
I've just open a case in Google about it (please, star it!): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70662064

Meanwhile, it is working with the "bq" command line, or with REST (which is the approach I took, until the Java API is fixed).

**Update on 15/12/21017:**

Google just advised me to use the "#standardSQL" notation at the beginning of the query. It works fine and I prefer it than using REST.

Here is an example:

```
ViewDefinition tableDefinition = ViewDefinition.newBuilder("#standardSQL\n  WITH A AS (select 1 as foo) SELECT * from A").build();
```